# Adding inherited generics to a generic list

Tags: c#, list, generics, inheritance

I'm trying to add objects to a list, where the objects are generics which inherit an interface.

Base class for listeners:

```
public class Listener<T> : IListener<T>
    where T : ICaller {

    public Listener()  {

    }

    public Type GetCallerType() {
        return typeof(T);
    }

    public virtual void Received(Connection connection, T obj) {}
}
```

Example listener:

```
public class ClientPacketListener<T> : Listener<T>
    where T : Packet {
}
```

I want to add them to this list:

```
Listener<ICaller> listeners = new Listener<ICaller>();
```

In this case, Packet inherits ICaller, so everything should be able to be cast down to the base types. The error is that it can't be cast however.
I've looked at some other questions, but they only work with a generic for `<T>`, not the listener class. Is there a way to get this to work or not?

Comment: Neither `Listener<T>` nor `ClientPacketListener<T>` implements `ICaller`. Please clarify what you want to do here and how you want it to behave.

Comment: T implements ICaller (Packet in this case). I want to make a generic list which I can loop over, but the class type should be generic in addition to the given type of T.

Comment: Did you mean `Listener<ICaller> listener = new ClientPacketListener<Packet>();`

Comment: Can you change `IListener<T>` code?

Comment: Well that's what I'm trying to do, but that doesn't work somehow, I have no idea why.

Comment: @IvanGritsenko Sure, what do you suggest?

Comment: @Randy Schouten, can you post you code of `IListener<ICaller>`?

Comment: @Randy Schouten, I suggest to use **covariant** generic argument type. see [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36057563/1770952).

Answer (score 0):

Just change here

```
 public interface IListener<out T>
 {

 }

public class ClientPacketListener : Listener<Packet>    
{
   //............ your code
}
```

then you can write down like this ..

```
 IListener<ICaller> listeners = new ClientPacketListener();
```

but not below one

```
 //Listener<ICaller> listeners = new ClientPacketListener();
```

**Edit:** The whole story is **Covariance** and **Contravariance**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx

Here a short note on that

> "out T" means that type T is "covariant". That restricts T to appear
>   only as a returned (outbound) value in methods of the generic class,
>   interface or method. The implication is that you can cast the
>   type/interface/method to an equivalent with a super-type of T. E.g.
>   ICovariant can be cast to ICovariant.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that!

I still have the problem that I want to have Packet as a ICaller generic, or else I can't any sort of object to listen for. It just says it can't cast Packet to ICaller even though Packet implements ICaller..

Comment: Do you want line like something this `Listener<ICaller> listeners = new ClientPacketListener();`

Comment: Exactly, but it can't cast Packet to ICaller even though Packet is implementing ICaller.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can resolve the problem if you would change your `IListener<T>` declaration to `IListener<out T>` making `T` **covariant**.

It should allow you to do this

```
IListener<ICaller> listener = new ClientPacketListener<Packet>();
```

For more information read [MSDN out (Generic Modifier)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd469487(v=vs.100).aspx).